# How to persist selected state of an image in a custom tableview cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

Ok, I have new dilemma.  I have been searching all over S.O. to find the answer, but I cannot seem to get any of the code to work. I have also looked at many tutorials and other resources but can't seem to find anything to help.

Here's the deal: I have a tableview with a custom cell with custom objects.  The custom cell contains an image that can be selected to indicate whether the type of transportation listed in the cell has been used or not.  The image changes from a grayed "unselected" state to a blue "selected" state (or back from "selected" to "unselected").  A tap gesture on the image fires up an alert view where the user can select "yes" or "no".  The alert view then causes the image to change to a "selected" or "unselected" state, essentially working like a checkmark.  This all works perfectly. (I added the alert view as a safeguard against an unintentional tap gesture on the image).

http://tinypic.com/r/s5d3s3/8

The problem occurs when the cell disappears during scrolling and then re-appears again, the image becomes deselected.  Lots of people have asked about this problem.  It looks like I need to: 
(1) set up a mutable array to hold the selections 
(2) perform some check in cellForRowAtIndexPath to tell the cell what to show 
(3) and, somewhere, set the state of the image selected so it can be added to the mutable array.

I've tried implementing ideas from some the given answers but a lot of them use a button or cell accessory.  Part of the problem is where to implement some of this code since I've got the gesture recognizer and alert view firing on the image.  Also, would saving the selection to nsuserdefaults keep the state of the image during scrolling as well, or would I need to deal with both problems separately? (meaning, add code to keep the state during scrolling as well as code to save to nsuserdefaults).  I've tried some S.O. answers to use nususerdefaults, but have the same problem...where do I put this code?  How do I save the image state instead of saving a button state or cell accessory state?

I also want to note that the tableview is embedded in a navigation controller and each cell goes to a detail view which adds to the problem when adding code to didSelectCellAtIndexPath (which most of the S.O. answers include). How do I single out the image that is tapped and not the whole cell (which often causes a segue to occur along with the image  selection).

Any kind of help would be most appreciated!! Thank you ahead of time. :)

Below is all my code:

```
**TRANSPORT.h**

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Transport : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *transportImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *usedTransportImage;

@end


**TRANSPORTDATACONTROLLER.h**

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Transport.h"

@interface TransportDataController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *transportDataArray;
-(NSMutableArray *)populateDataSource;

@end


**TRANSPORTDATACONTROLLER.m**

#import "TransportDataController.h"

@implementation TransportDataController

-(NSMutableArray *)populateDataSource
{
    _transportDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    Transport *transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];

    transportData.name = @"Bus";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bus"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Helicopter";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Helicopter"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Truck";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Truck"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Boat";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Boat"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Bicycle";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bicycle"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Motorcycle";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Motorcycle"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Plane";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Plane"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Train";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Train"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Car";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Car"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Scooter";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Scooter"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    transportData = [[Transport alloc] init];
    transportData.name = @"Caravan";
    transportData.transportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Caravan"];
    transportData.usedTransportImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    [_transportDataArray addObject:transportData];

    return _transportDataArray; 
}

@end


**TRANSPORTCELL.h**

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TransportCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *transportImageView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *grayedImageView;

@end


**MAINTABLEVIEWCONTROLLER.h**

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Transport.h"
#import "TransportDataController.h"
#import "DetailTableViewController.h"

@interface MainTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) TransportDataController *transportController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *dataSource;

@end


**MAINTABLEVIEWCONTROLLER.m**

#import "MainTableViewController.h"
#import "TransportCell.h"

@interface MainTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainTableViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _transportController = [[TransportDataController alloc] init];
    self.dataSource = _transportController.populateDataSource;
    self.title = @"Transportation Types";

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _dataSource.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"mainCell";
    TransportCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[TransportCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Transport *transportData = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = transportData.name;
    cell.transportImageView.image = transportData.transportImage;
    cell.grayedImageView.image = transportData.usedTransportImage;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *grayedImageTouched = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(transportImageTapped:)];
    grayedImageTouched.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [cell.grayedImageView addGestureRecognizer:grayedImageTouched];
    cell.grayedImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


    return cell;
}


-(void)transportImageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    UIImageView *selectedImageView = (UIImageView *)[gesture view];
    UIImage *grayedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];
    UIImage *darkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-color"];

    UIAlertController *transportAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Yes, it's true..." message:@"I have used this type of transport before." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [transportAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

        NSLog(@"cancel");

    }]];

    [transportAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

        if (selectedImageView.image == grayedImage)
        {
            selectedImageView.image = grayedImage;
            [selectedImageView setImage:grayedImage];

        }
        else
        {
            selectedImageView.image = darkImage;
            [selectedImageView setImage:darkImage];

        }

        if (selectedImageView.image == darkImage)
        {
            selectedImageView.image = darkImage;
            [selectedImageView setImage:darkImage];

        }
        else
        {
            selectedImageView.image = grayedImage;
            [selectedImageView setImage:grayedImage];

        }

        NSLog(@"has taken this transport before");


    }]];

    [transportAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"No" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

        if (selectedImageView.image == darkImage)
        {
            selectedImageView.image = grayedImage;
            [selectedImageView setImage:grayedImage];

        }
        else
        {
            selectedImageView.image = grayedImage;
            [selectedImageView setImage:grayedImage];
        }

        if (selectedImageView.image == grayedImage)
        {
            selectedImageView.image = grayedImage;
            [selectedImageView setImage:grayedImage];
        }

        NSLog(@"has not taken this transport before");
    }]];

    [self presentViewController:transportAlert animated:YES completion:nil];

}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
    {
        DetailTableViewController *detailController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailController.transport = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] .row];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: If "yes" is clicked, do you want the image to be dark? As of now, it looks like that "yes" block isn't really doing anything...

Comment: @ Lyndsey...Ah! This is something I forgot to mention.  Once I added the alert view into the equation, the bool logic got weird and would not work. The code above is what I came up with.  It actually works perfectly even though it looks like it wouldn't.  That problem caused me some anguish for quite a while.  But to answer your question, "yes" would cause the image to be dark instead of grayed out.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. Check out my answer then to see how you can simplify your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suspect, you need to change your datasource data upon button click such that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can load the desired image appropriately. In this case, you can simply change your `TransportCell`'s `usedTransportImage` (i.e. the `UIImage` tied to the `UIGestureRecognizer) to dark or gray depending on the alert view's input.

As your code stands now though, your logic within your alert blocks is flawed to the point that I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish -- your "Yes" block always leaves your image as is, your "No" block always sets your image to gray, and you're repeatedly setting the image multiple times within each block. I'm guessing that maybe you want a "Yes" response to set the `usedTransportImage` to dark and a "No" response to set the `usedTransportImage` to gray (?)... So using that assumption as an example, this is what I recommend:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ...

    // Set the UITapGestureRecognizer's image view's tag to
    // indexPath.row
    cell.grayedImageView.tag = indexPath.row;

    ...


    return cell;
}

- (void)transportImageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    // Fetch the datasource object associated with the current row
    Transport *transportData = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:gesture.view.tag inSection:0];

    UIAlertController *transportAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Yes, it's true..." message:@"I have used this type of transport before." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [transportAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

        NSLog(@"cancel");

    }]];

    [transportAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

        NSLog(@"has taken this transport before");

        // Create the image within the block so it's only
        // created if needed
        UIImage *darkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-color"];

        // Set the Transport object's "used" image to the
        // darkened image
        transportData.usedTransportImage = darkImage;

        // Replace the old Transport object associated with the
        // current row with the updated Transport object
        [self.dataSource replaceObjectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag withObject:transportData];

        // Reload the table data at that row so it reflects those changes
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    }]];

    [transportAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"No" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

        NSLog(@"has not taken this transport before");

        // Create the image within the block so it's only
        // created if needed
        UIImage *grayedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stamp-grayed"];

        // Set the Transport object's "used" image to the
        // grayed image
        transportData.usedTransportImage = grayedImage;

        // Replace the old Transport object associated with the
        // current row with the updated Transport object
        [self.dataSource replaceObjectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag withObject:transportData];

        // Reload the table data at that row so it reflects those changes
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    }]];

    [self presentViewController:transportAlert animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

And if you want help for the second part of your question about preventing the view's transition upon button press, please post your code from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: @Lyndsey...THANKS for taking the time to look at this, but xcode threw a fit on the first line regarding indexPath.row. I recall trying to call indexpath several times in my struggle and could never find a place to use it. I had tried to add a tableview property to call on as recommended in other posts, but nothing worked except the crazy code I shared above.  Also, I currently do not have didSelectRowAtIndexPath implemented since nothing was working in it and I have not needed it for anything that's currently going on.

Comment: @IWannaLearn Updated. As for the view's transition, if you're not using didSelectRowAtIndexPath to make the transition, what are you using?

Comment: I've updated my code with what you've got here.  I love the idea of simplifying!  At the moment xcode tells me that the property 'tag' not found on object of type 'UITapGestureRecognizer*'.  No errors on anything else and I'm dying to see if this works.  For transition, I'm using storyboard's prepareForSegue.  The tableview is embedded in a nav controller. Thanks again for your ideas.

Comment: @IWannaLearn Whoops again... Updated. (The gesture's *view* should have the tag...not the gesture.)

Comment: @Lyndsey...OMG it worked!! Thanks so much! Selections remain selected on scrolling.

Comment: @IWannaLearn Glad to hear. :)

Answer (score 2):

Step away from the details and think about what you're doing.

A table view presents information about an ordered collection of things.

The things are the data model. The table view is the view object, and the view controller is the controller object in the MVC design pattern.

When the user interacts with the view in a way that needs to make a persistent change, the controller should record the changes in the model and tell the view to update it's appearance.

Then, if a cell scrolls off-screen and then back on-screen, the data source should set up the recycled cell with the new state for that entry from the data model.

For a non-sectioned table view it's quite common to store the data model as an NSArray of some sort of data object. You can create a custom data container object or just use a dictionary.

Let's say we have a custom data object.

Simply add a property to your data object that tells whether or not a transportation item has been used or not.

When the user taps on the view object, the view controller should respond to the messages from the gesture recognizer by changing the "has been used" property of the data model object for the specific index path and then tell the view to redraw itself.

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, set the view object based on the state of the "has been used" flag. Since you saved the change of state into the data model, next time the user displays a cell for a given index in your table data, it shows the changed state.

Comment: @Duncan...thank you for the explanation.  I will be printing this out and digesting the information.  Everything is a learning experience. :)

Comment: @Duncan...I have been mulling over your suggestions. Is the above advice only to persist the cell states just while scrolling or should it persist the value of "has been used" even when the app is terminated? (because the changes I made do not do so).  Should I be using this in conjunction with nsuserdefaults?  So far, nothing I've tried works. I followed these three steps: I added a bool property to my data object called usedTransportIsSelected, I set the value for it in the code for the gesture recognizer, and then set the view in cellforRowatindexpath - but it does not persist. Any insight?

Comment: Most likely both. In modern iOS versions, the user can swap your app to the background at any moment, and then the system can quietly kill it while you are in the background. You get notified when you're moving to the background, so you can defer saving your app state until then (as long as you can do it quickly).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do as given below. Changed the implementation of transportImageTapped method. Code is not tested so there is a possibility of minor error. Let me know if this helps.
Create a NSMutableArray say NSMutableArray *selected;

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"mainCell";
TransportCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[TransportCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

Transport *transportData = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.nameLabel.text = transportData.name;
cell.transportImageView.image = transportData.transportImage;
if([selected containsObject:indexPath]) {
    cell.grayedImageView.image = transportData.usedTransportImage;
} else {
    cell.grayedImageView.image = transportData.deSelectedTransportImage;
}

UITapGestureRecognizer *grayedImageTouched = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(transportImageTapped:)];
grayedImageTouched.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[cell.grayedImageView addGestureRecognizer:grayedImageTouched];
cell.grayedImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


return cell;
}

-(void)transportImageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
CGPoint point= [gesture locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *theIndexPath = [theTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];

UIAlertController *transportAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Yes, it's true..." message:@"I have used this type of transport before." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[transportAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

    NSLog(@"cancel");

}]];

[transportAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

    if(selected containsObject:theIndexPath ) {
        //Already selected - Remove the selection
        [selected removeObject:theIndexPath];
    } else {
        // Set the object as selected
        [selected addObjetc:theIndexPath];
    }

    NSLog(@"has taken this transport before");
    NSArray* indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:theIndexPath, nil];
    // Launch reload for the two index path
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}]];

[transportAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"No" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

    if(selected containsObject:theIndexPath ) {
        //Already selected - Remove the selection
        [selected removeObject:theIndexPath];
    } else {
        // Set the object as selected
        [selected addObjetc:theIndexPath];
    }

    NSLog(@"has not taken this transport before");
    NSArray* indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:theIndexPath, nil];
    // Launch reload for the two index path
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}]];

[self presentViewController:transportAlert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Comment: @ArunGupta...Thank you for this. It looked promising and I tried it but I believe the weird logic I had to do when I added the alertview is causing it not to work (The images are not changing on selection).  I will keep messing with it to see if I can get it to go.

Comment: Have you checked the change i have made in cellForRowAtIndexPath? What issue you are facing?

Comment: @Arun...I get an error that says "no known class method for selector 'indexPathForRowAtPoint'"